# How to create a column from another df according to matching columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a df named population with a column named countries. I want to merge rows so they reflect regions = ( africa, west hem, asia, europe, mideast). I have another df named regionref from kaggle that have all countries of the world and the region they are associated with.

How do I create a new column in the population df that has the corresponding regions for the countries in the country column, using the region column from the kaggle dataset.

so essentially this is the population dataframe

```
CountryName 1960 1950 ...

US
Zambia 
India
```

And this is the regionref dataset

```
Country  Region      GDP...

US       West Hem
Zambia   Africa
India    Asia
```

And I want the population df to look like

```
CountryName  Region    1960   1950 ...

US           West Hem
Zambia       Africa
India        Asia
```

EDIT: I tried the concatenation but for some reason the two columns are not recognizing the same values

```
population['Country Name'].isin(regionref['Country']).value_counts()
```

This returned False for all values, as in there are no values in common.

And this is the output, as you can see there are values in common
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a join functionality, or to say, concatenate, in pandas way.

Given two DataFrames pop, region:

```py
pop = pd.DataFrame([['US', 1000, 2000], ['CN', 2000, 3000]], columns=['CountryName', 1950, 1960])

CountryName 1950    1960
0   US  1000    2000
1   CN  2000    3000

region = pd.DataFrame([['US', 'AMER', '5'], ['CN', 'ASIA', '4']], columns = ['Country', 'Region', 'GDP'])

Country Region  GDP
0   US  AMER    5
1   CN  ASIA    4
```

You can do:

```py
pd.concat([region.set_index('Country'), pop.set_index('CountryName')], axis = 1)\
    .drop('GDP', axis =1)

    Region  1950    1960
US  AMER    1000    2000
CN  ASIA    2000    3000
```

The axis = 1 is for concatenating horizontally. You have to set column index for joining it correctly.

Comment: for some reason the columns aren't recognizing the values they have in common. Is this because they're still type object do I need to change to string?

Comment: The single value must be string. Do pop['CountryName'].values and
region['Country'].values to check if there're spaces in the common names.

Comment: you were right, the regionref df had whitespace. Thanks !!